# Log4j2.3 rotating log file number incorrectly

Tags: log4j2

We are using Log4j2.3 version for logging and using xml configuration.
      Here it is like -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="testingAppender" fileName="Test.log"
            filePattern="logs/Test.log.%i">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5p] %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %m %n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="testingLogger" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef  ref="testingAppender" level="debug" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Log files are rotating fine. 
But the LATEST log file is having highest rolling number 
Example - Test.log7, where it should be Test.log0.
Log file numbers are rotating in reverse order.

Need help in this.

Comment: Actually, highest log file is fine. But when having mutiple log files they are rotating in reverse order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not incorrect but the default behavior. To get your intended behavior, try setting `fileIndex` attribute `min`.

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" fileIndex="min" />
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. It's working very fine. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.3/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/DefaultRolloverStrategy.html